# How can I bind a click event to a function in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have the following JSON object:

```
{Countries: [America, China, Russia, etc]}
```

I have a function defined in my countries.component.ts(typescript) component file for EACH country:

```
...
America() { ... }
China() { ... }
Russia() { ... }
etc
```

Suppose I have a ngFor in my component template that iterates over the JSON object.I want to be able to bind a click event in such a way:

```
<ul *ngFor="let country of Countries">
  <li>
    <a (click)="{{country}}()" >{{country}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

when I click on the "America" anchor element it will invoke the "America()" function.

Is there a way to bind a click event to a dynamic function name (even though the functions are statically defined in the appropriate component class (ie. America, China, Russia, etc are defined) ?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation doesn't seem to work the way you tried.
A possible solution to your problem is to give arguments to the function in `*ngFor`.

code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `


  <ul *ngFor="let x of countries">
  <li>
    <a (click)="doThis(x)" >{{x}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){console.clear()}



  public countries:any[]= ['America','China', 'Russia', 'Germany']



  doThis(x){


    console.log('life is life in '+ x)
  }



}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/54X01q50pdIZKjYMg28G?p=preview)